# Ubuntu 16.04: Messed up Pulseaudio with firejail

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio

Ubuntu 16:04, fresh install. Decided to try and up the security a bit by securing browsers in `firejail`. Didn't went as I expected. The sequence of steps looked like this:

- installed `firejail`
- tried to run `firecfg --fix-sound` as suggested [here](https://firejail.wordpress.com/documentation-2/). It didn't work, firecfg is simply abscent in the installation. Looked it up via `apt-get`, no luck as well.
- sound starts working erratically. Sometimes it worked only in one browser and not in other, but after I restarted browser it started working again. I didn't pay much attention until VLC refused to play audio. I checked browsers, it didn't work as well.
- I tried [this fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765538/ubuntu-16-04-audio-not-working-correctly). Reboot. No good.
- Removed firejail. Reboot. Nada.
- I read that the sound problem was only present on pulseaudio 8.0 so I tried to update it to 9. I used instructions provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/872260/how-can-i-update-pulseaudio-to-latest-9-0-version/872267). At this point I'm not sure what happened, but the gist of it is that I did everything as it was described, but when I checked `pulseaudio --version` it showed `8.0`. I tried running the aforementioned sequence one more time, but the update still didn't go through.
- I tried the first fix again and somehow it worked and I got sound, but my sound control is completely scrambled. The speaker icon on the dashboard is greyed out and I cannot adjust volume level via system tools. Luckily I use external speakers with a separate volume controller. `pulseaudio --version` still shows `8`.

What I can do to fix this mess?

Comment: I too am having issues with sound. I filed this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1809767) and here's [video](https://youtu.be/aVXsGi-GcgY) of my problem.